# Can tensorflow handle categorical features with multiple inputs within one column?

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix, categorical-data

For example, I have data in the following csv format:

> 1, 2, 1:3:4, 2
>
> 0, 1, 3:5, 1
>
> ...

Each column seperated by comma represent one feature. Normally, a feature is one-hot(*e.g. col0, col1, col3*), but in this case, the feature for *col2* has multiple inputs(seperated by colon).

I'm sure tensorflow can handle one-hot feature with **sparse tensor**, but I'm not sure if it could handle feature with multiple inputs like *col2*?

And if ok, how should it be represented in tensorflow's **sparse tensor**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TensorFlow has some string processing ops which can handle lists within CSVs. I'd read the list as a string column first, the process it like this:

```
def process_list_column(list_column, dtype=tf.float32):
  sparse_strings = tf.string_split(list_column, delimiter=":")
  return tf.SparseTensor(indices=sparse_strings.indices,
                         values=tf.string_to_number(sparse_strings.values,
                                                    out_type=dtype),
                         dense_shape=sparse_strings.dense_shape)
```

An example of using this function:

```
# csv_input.csv contains:
# 1,2,1:3:4,2
# 0,1,3:5,1
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["csv_input.csv"])
# Read two lines, batched
_, lines = tf.TextLineReader().read_up_to(filename_queue, 2)
columns = tf.decode_csv(lines, record_defaults=[[0], [0], [""], [0]])
columns[2] = process_list_column(columns[2], dtype=tf.int32)

with tf.Session() as session:
  coordinator = tf.train.Coordinator()
  tf.train.start_queue_runners(session, coord=coordinator)

  print(session.run(columns))

  coordinator.request_stop()
  coordinator.join()
```

Outputs:

```
[array([1, 0], dtype=int32), 
 array([2, 1], dtype=int32), 
 SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]]), 
     values=array([1, 3, 4, 3, 5], dtype=int32), 
     dense_shape=array([2, 3])),
 array([2, 1], dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!